# Can the below CSS be further simplified?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Can the below CSS be further simplified?

```
 .firstLevel .secondLevel .k-button,
 .firstLevel .secondLevel .k-input
 .firstLevel .secondLevel .k-picker-wrap,
 .firstLevel .secondLevel .k-textbox {
    border-style: none;
 }
```

Comment: are you sure your code is correct?

Comment: @SreetamDas Yes, i'm trying to restrict CSS to those controls available at secondLevel. Its working and the controls which is at secondLevel element has no border. I would like to simplify it further. Is it possible or is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends greatly on your HTML structure and what other classes you are using.

The following slector will match all elements that have a class name starting with `k-` **AND** has parent with the `.secondLevel` class and a greater parent with the `.firstLevel` class. :

```
.firstLevel .secondLevel [class^="k-"] {border-style:none;}
```

Here is an example :

```css
.firstLevel .secondLevel div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.firstLevel .secondLevel [class^="k-"] {
  border-color: red;
}
.firstLevel .secondLevel div:before{
  content:' Class : ' attr(class);
 }
```

```html
<div class="firstLevel">
  <div class="secondLevel">
    <div class="k-something"></div>
    <div class="k-otherthing"></div>
    <div class="m-something"></div>
    <div class="k-something-else"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```